# If $f_n \to f$ in distribution then does $\int_0^1 f_n \to \int_0^1 f$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions on $(0,1)$. Suppose $\sup_{n\geq 1} |f_n|$ is a well-defined and measurable function. If $f_n \to f$ in distribution then does $\int_0^1 f_n \to \int_0^1 f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $f_n(x)= nI_{(0,\frac1  n)}(x)$ and $f=0$. Then $sup_n |f_n(x)|=\frac  1 x <\infty$ for each $x$ and $f_n \to f$ in distribution but $\int f_n =1$ and $\int f=0$.